# How do I access the same property from 2 separate ViewModels without dependency injection?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I have my application setup this way.

My `App.xaml` contains the DataTemplates for my views which are `UserControl`s

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:ProtectionViewModel}">
            <view:ProtectionView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:CloudViewModel}">
            <view:CloudView />
        </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then I have my `MainWindow.xaml` which consists of 2 buttons and a `ContentPresenter`

```
<RadioButton    Content="Y"
                FontSize="16"
                Foreground="LightGray"
                Padding="0,0,0,1"
                Command="{Binding ShowProtectionViewCommand}"/>

<RadioButton    Content="Z"
                FontSize="16"
                Foreground="LightGray"
                Padding="0,0,0,1"
                Command="{Binding ShowCloudViewCommand}"/>


<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
```

And as of right now when I click one of the buttons, it changes the `CurrentView` to a ViewModel which then changes the View based on the ViewModel as shown previously in `App.xaml`

By doing this

```
    private object _currentView;
    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set
        {
            _currentView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
public ProtectionViewModel ProtectionViewModel { get; set; } = new ProtectionViewModel();
public CloudViewModel CloudViewModel { get; set; } = new CloudViewModel();


ShowProtectionViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { CurrentView = ProtectionViewModel; });
ShowCloudViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { CurrentView = CloudViewModel; });
```

That all works perfectly, I can switch the view and it keeps the same DataContext which is great. The issue is that, what if I want a global property that I can access from multiple ViewModels, what would I do?

Looking at this image which I found [over here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224371/help-with-complex-mvvm-multiple-views/308592#308592) 
 I wanted to create something along that style but I don't know how I would implement the "Common VM".
[image]

All of my Views have their own ViewModel, the `MainWindow` has `MainViewModel`, the `ProtectionView` has `ProtectionViewModel` etc.

Comment: Are your 3 view-models *derived* from `CommonVm` or do you want each of them to share one instance of it

Comment: Assuming the latter, why not make each view-model expose a property of type `CommonVm` (that is your single, global instance of `CommonVm`) and then make the xaml bind to that?

Comment: Sharing one instance would be the same as derriving from it, no? There should be one instance of the CommonVm that all VM's should be able to access if they need to is what I was thinking.

Comment: No it would not be the same.  Deriving from it would mean you would effectively have 3 instances of `CommonVm`.  Sharing one would mean there is only one instance

Comment: `Assuming the latter, why not make each view-model expose a property of type CommonVm (that is your single, global instance of CommonVm)` I don't quite follow what you mean.

Comment: 1. Create a single, global instance of `CommonVM`at app startup.  Construct each of the 3 Vm types (`VM1`, `VM2`, `VM3` aka `ProtectionViewModel`, `CloudViewModel`, etc ) and pass in that single instance of CommonVM to each of them in their constructors.  Give each of those view models a public property that returns that `CommonVM`.  Bind your  XAML to that property.

Comment: But that's dependency injection, no?

Comment: It's one way to give them access to that global model.    Not sure what the problem with that is but there are others.  You could give `CommonVm` a public static instance property of it's own type that they can just "know about" and then expose the property that way

Comment: Creating a singleton instance of CommonVm would require me to create a new instance of the CommonVm property that I create in each Vm no?

Comment: Each VM can *implement* the property but whether each VM's implementation returns a different object or the exact same singleton instance is up to you.  I don't mean to be dismissive I think you need to do some reading on C#.  I'm explaining some fairly fundamental aspects of it here that you do not seem to grasp.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that, let's say I create CommonVm and implement a singleton pattern, and then create a public property of type CommonVm in any of my other Vm's, I can't access any properties from the public property because it would be null, which means that I would have to create a new instance of it, making the singleton pointless.

Comment: No they would not be null.  Because their implementations of the property would just go grab the static instance.

Comment: But you can't bind to something that's static.

Comment: You aren't.  I am not talking about a static class I am talking about a singleton instance that is exposed by CommonVm from its static property BUT is exposed by each instance of  `ProtectionViewModel` and `CloudViewModel` from non-static properties.  Their non-static properties are just implemented to return the same  singleton by accessing `CommonVm`'s static one.  As long as the static property in CommonVm returns an object created via operator new() it will all work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't think an answer was going to be needed but we're running out fo comment space under the question so let me illustrated.

Do it like this Like this (you'll have to pretend that I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

```
public class CommonVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Static instance property

    public static CommonVm Instance { get; } = new CommonVm();

    // Non static properties against which you can bind.
    // Imagine I wrote full implementations with INPC

    public int PropertyA {  get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }  
}
```

Then

```
public class CloudViewModel
{
    public CommonVm CommonObject => CommonVm.Instance;
}
```

Then in XAML suppose your DataContext is an instance of `CloudViewModel`

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CommonObject.PropertyB}"/>
```

Whatever you want to say about that, it sure ain't Dependency Injection

Comment: Yeah I should of answered that last one, I managed to figure out where you were going with that, but I appreciate the answer.